# How to write a multi-line text-widget into a single line of a text file?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-files, enter, text-widget

I created a `GUI` that uses a text file as a database. Every line in the text file is an entry. Every item on each line is separated by "|", like the following structure: "*ID|Title|Counter|Keywords|DATA|Last Update*". Two of these items (Counter and Data) are shown/added/edited/ via a `text widget` of `tkinter`.

A text widget can have `multiple lines` including `breaks`, which should be allowed in my program. However, in the end I need to have every entry on one line in the text file, otherwise errors reading the file will follow obviously. For example, I have a scale bar which allows me to scroll through all entries which will provide an `out of range` error, since the last added line in the file does not have all the items according to the entry structure.

I am wondering whether it is possible to remove the `breaks` of the text widget when writing into the file and adding them when reading the file again. I thought of using the functions `str.strip("\n")` and `str.replace(".", ".\n")`, but this doesn't work.

Here is the necessary part of my code only focusing on one text widget for example:

```
import tkinter as tk

data_var = tk.StringVar()

sfile = open(DATAFILE, "a+")
temp_data = datatext.get("1.0", "end-1c") #Get whole text from text widget
temp_data.strip("\n")
data_var.set(temp_data) #Save text into var

#ID|Title|Counter|Keywords|DATA|Last Update
writeline = ("\n" + str(dataID_var.get()) + "|" +
                                title_var.get() + "|" +
                                counter_var.get() + "|" +
                                keywords_var.get() + "|" +
                                data_var.get() + "|" +
                                lastupdate_var.get())

sfile.write(writeline) #Write data into file
sfile.close #Close file
```

This is the code to read the file and show it in the entry:

```
sfile = open(DATAFILE, "r")
lines = sfile.readlines()
sfile.close

dataentry = (scalebar.get())-1       #Get the entryID from scalebar
rawcontent = lines[dataentry]         #Get line from lines with request entryID
content = rawcontent.split("|")      #Split the input in pieces to use the following seperatly
content = content.replace(".", ".\n")

#ID|Title|Counter|Keywords|DATA|Last Update

#Set textvariable to content and update text widget
data_var.set(content[4])
datatext["state"]="normal"              #Make sure you can edit the Text widget
datatext.delete(1.0, "end")             #Clear text widget first
datatext.insert(tk.END, data_var.get()) #show new content in text widget
```

Why doesn't this work? (The first part `str.strip("\n")` is already not working I have seen manually in the text file)
How can I make this work?
Could I deny the usage the `enter-key` as temporarily solution?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why not store the newlines as a literal `\n` in your text file, then replace it with an actual newline character when you need to display or process it?

Comment: Additionally, I'd strongly recommend using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module instead of trying to roll your own solution. It can easily handle using the `|` character as a field delimiter if that's a requirement.

Comment: instead of `strip('\n')` you can just do `.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: Unfortunately, `str.replace("\n", "")` does not work either. Same problem. I guess I need to dive into `*.csv` files then. Are you sure `csv` files kan handle multiple lines of a text widget in one row?